# I have created an API in which I am updating some parameters

Tags: node.js

If I am updating all parameters it's working fine but if I am updating 
    separately any parameter then other parameters getting null.
    I don't know how to handle this condition.
    I want that if I am updating one parameter it should not affect other 
    properties.

```js
router.put('/session/addActivity/:sessionID',function(req,res){
    Session.findOne({_id:req.params.sessionID},function(err,session){
        if(err){
            return res.send(err);
        }
        if(session){
            session.qanda.isEnable = req.body.qanda_enabled;
            session.qanda.isModerate = req.body.qanda_moderation;
            session.qanda.isCommentEnable = req.body.qanda_comments;
            session.qanda.isAnonymousResponse = req.body.qanda_anonymousResponse;
            session.poll.isEnable = req.body.poll_enabled;
            session.poll.isMultiSelect = req.body.poll_MultiSelect;
            session.poll.answerLimit = req.body.poll_answerLimit;
            session.pulse.isEnable = req.body.pulse_enabled;
            session.pulse.isAnonymousResponse = req.body.pulse_anonymousResponse;
            session.pulse.votesLimitPerUser = req.body.pulse_votesPerUser;
            session.save(function(err,session){
                if(err){
                    return res.send(err);
                }
                else{
                    res.json(session);
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Sorry for that @alex

Comment: Please give me some solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're explicitly setting the parameters, regardless of whether the data in `req.body` is set or not.

So, if it's not set (null) it's then clearing the corresponding property on your `session` object.

The only way to sort this out would be to explicitly check each parameter on your `req.body` object first:

```
if("undefined" !== typeof req.body.qanda_enabled){
    session.qanda.isEnable = req.body.qanda_enabled;
}

if("undefined" !== typeof req.body.qanda_moderation){
    session.qanda.isModerate = req.body.qanda_moderation;
}

if("undefined" !== typeof req.body.qanda_comments){
       session.qanda.isCommentEnable = req.body.qanda_comments;
}

if("undefined" !== typeof req.body.qanda_anonymousResponse){
       session.qanda.isAnonymousResponse = req.body.qanda_anonymousResponse;
}

//etc.....
```